# Vue/Vuex indeterminate checkbox

Tags: checkbox, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I can't tell how to be able to read value from vuex, while simultaneusly being able to toggle state between indeterminate (deletes prop from vuex), false, and true. In order to keep state between the 3, I need to use data value, while nonetheless reflecting value of vuex which can simply be undefined (or surely changed from outside of the component).

I would rather not pollute state with checkbox specific properties such as it's toggle cycle or indeterminate prop. PS: although I could probably use getter.

```

```
<template>
  <div class="check-level">
    <input type='checkbox' :checked="bogus1.bool" @change='bogus1(bogus1.check+1)' :indeterminate.prop="bogus1.indeterminate">

  </div>
</template>


<script>
import store from "/client/vuex/store.js"
import { mapMutations, mapState, mapGetters } from 'vuex';
export default {
  props: [
    "value",
    "index",
    "name",
    "level"
  ],
  data: function (){
    return {
    }
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters([
      "toggle_level_state"
    ]),
    bogus1: {
      get(){
        return this.toggle_level_state[this.index].skills[this.name].levels[this.level]
      },
      set(val) {
        var payload = {index: this.index, name: this.name, level: this.level, check:val}
        console.log(val)
        this.upsert_level(payload)
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapMutations([
      "upsert_level"
    ]),
  }
}
</script>
```

```

Comment: I don't quite understand. Can you clarify with the code samples (your vuex store; your component where you dispatch the relevant action)? Also, did you read up on the Form Handling part of the vuex documentation? You can find it here: https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/forms.html

Comment: Show what you've done so far, it's your issue is unclear. Create a workable fiddle, for example from this template: https://jsfiddle.net/wostex/u2yoLgLb/4/

Comment: I run modified version of vue which bridges meteor into it, so my last working example is that, that uses tracker which is computed on steroids. Are you sure you know how checkboxes work if looking to use indeterminate prop?

Comment: added code, claims that the computed setter isn't a function

Comment: The issue may have been that I didn't clone the state at all to parse checkbox state at all. I'll check on that later.